# Тетраграмма и тетраграмматон

Tags: этимология, греческий

В чем отличие слов "тетраграмма" и "тетраграмматон"? Если их нет, то почему различное написание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем написание различное?!

Здесь просто два варианта термина. Почему их именно два - сказать трудно, видимо традиция.

греч. τετραγράμμα, τετραγράμματον, 
Первое от греч. τετρα - четыре, γράμμα - буква, надпись, письмо
Второе - еще и с - персонифицирующим морфом τον (насколько понимаю, по семантике близким к русскому суффиксу -ель").

Насчет значения - синонимы. Я было решил, что тетраграмма - более широкое понятие, т.к. оно может использоваться вне какого-либо религиозного и мистического наполнения, в технике, гелогии, электронике... Но убедился, что и для этих значений тетраграмофон вполне используется.

Так что никакой сколько-нибудь значимой разницы я тут не вижу. Ни в написании, ни в значении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Различное как раз в наличии/отсутствии этого морфа, я не знал, что он означает.

 Видимо, под тетраграммой понимается сама надпись, а Тетраграмматон – Бог, то есть тот, кого эта надпись подразумевает. А потом значения смешались. Хотя это лишь предположения.

Answer (score 0):

Тетраграмматон(реже -тетраграмма) - это условное обозначение Бога,состоящее из четырех согласных  букв hwhy.Подробнее здесь.http://www.bibleist.ru/biblio/tetragrammaton.pdf
.

Comment: Спасибо, но я знаю значение. Вопрос именно в том, почему два варианта написания, отличаются ли они чем-то.